# How do I change the header color in my vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, header

Working on a code to update Header Color. With my current code I'm running into a notification for runtime error "424"- object required. I know the issue is the second line that starts with "With," but I guess I don't understand why its saying there is no object when its defined in the line above?

```
    Sub HeaderForm()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Range("B7")
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "Name - " & WorkRng.Value
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader.Font.Color()
    End With
    End With
    End Sub`
```

Comment: `With` is for object types. `.Color` is not an object. Might be helpful to read the [`With`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) docs.

Comment: ...and you typically don't make assignments when opening a `With` block

Comment: Excel headers and footers are formatted using special codes which are added to the text to be displayed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers